# Changing Text color located in an iframe (text comes from a .txt file)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, textcolor

I have a .txt file called LeaderBoardScores and I have the file within an iframe 
I would like to know if it is possible to change the text color of the .txt file that is within the iframe?
Also is it possible to solve this with JQuery/Javascript or simple css? 
Thank you in advance for any assistance !

Comment: Plaintext files are plain text files. You might want to look into HTML.

Comment: That isn't really an opinion as its a leaderboard and I have my php set up to save to the .txt file which is why I'm using a .txt file in the first place. I take it its not possible to try and style a .txt file?

Comment: It's not possible to style a text file directly. But you can write a program that reads the file and converts it to something that can be styled.

Comment: Pull the text from the file with php and convert to html